# What are the system requirements to run AUTOMATIC1111's Stable Diffusion Web UI on an Apple-silicon Mac?

Tags: stable-diffusion, automatic1111-sd-web-ui

I have a Mac Mini M1. Will my device be able to run Stable Diffusion Web UI?

I have read that [Automatic1111's Stable Diffusion Web UI](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) is the most popular application software to run Stable Diffusion. I have searched the GitHub repository for the system requirements but I haven't been able to find them.

Searching the Web using Google shows me the [following top result](https://aituts.com/stable-diffusion-on-windows-automatic1111/):

> You need to meet the following requirements.
>
> - 16GB RAM.
> - NVIDIA (GTX 7xx or newer) GPU with at least 2GB VRAM.
> - Linux or Windows 7/8/10/11+
> - At least 10GB disk space.
>
> Jul 19, 2023
>
> AiTuts
> https://aituts.com › Blog

But following that there is [this feature request](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/issues/6779) from the GitHub repo:

> [Feature Request]: State minimal hardware requirements in the Readme
>
> Jan 15, 2023 — State how much RAM (or other limitations) the PC has to have in order for ... https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/ ...

The first link doesn't include the source of the system requirements, and the second link is a request asking to include the hardware requirements on the Readme.md file of the GitHub repository.

It's worth mentioning that `Readme.md` includes a link to
[Installation on Apple Silicon](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Installation-on-Apple-Silicon), a page hosted in the repository wiki. This page asks for feedback and doesn't mention system requirements like required RAM or a supported operative system name and version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are asking specifically about the requirements for the WebUI here, but the *real* question will be the minimum requirements for the model you will be using, along with some other factors mentioned below.

Stable Diffusion has released a number of models over time, and things have moved so fast I've practically lost track of them all.

Essentially the two main models in use today are SD 1.5 (from last year) and SDXL 1.0 (recently released):

- SD 1.5 was optimized for 512x512 images and has lower overall requirements, so many people continue to run that (or a model trained using it as the base).  However, performance isn't the only reason some people stick to 1.5 - There are  more "add-ons" for 1.5 at this point.  This is to be expected since 1.5 has had time to "mature", and SDXL 1.0 was just recently released.
- SDXL is a more advanced model and is optimized for 1024x1024 images.  As a result, it has higher requirements in order to achieve the same "class" of performance, but even beyond the resolution, its advances are at least a generational leap ahead of SD1.5.

Additional considerations:

- Performance: As you might can tell from the above, another factor here is your performance expectation.  "Minimum" might mean that it will *run*, but will you be satisfied with the performance?  Image generation on a high-end NVIDIA with 24GB of VRAM might run ~1 second per image, but that 2GB "minimum" that is listed may mean upwards of a minute per 512x512 image (theoretical example).
- Image quality: There are other "tricks" that are done in order to make larger models "fit" in small VRAM sizes that will impact overall quality.  I've long been interested in an apples-to-apples comparison of various "optimization" settings and VRAM sizes when it comes to image results, but I haven't seen any so far.  It's entirely likely they exist and I've just missed them.

As for the Mac Mini, I can't speak to it personally, but my *guess* is that the unified memory is both a blessing and a curse.  It likely means that you have a better chance of *running* larger models, since the GPU can access more memory, but I just don't know what the performance impact is for SD on that architecture.

---

Disk Space:  As @FranckDernoncourt mentioned, the real *minimum* requirement is probably somewhat under 10GB, but keep in mind that's *just* for the WebUI, base model, and dependencies.  The minimum *you'll* need depends on how you will use it.

The big adders above and beyond the base minimum are going to be:

- Additional models (checkpoints):  One of the greatest benefits to running Stable Diffusion locally is that you can load any of hundreds of custom-trained models.  Want to generate images that look like they were created with balloons?  There's a model for that.  One for Disney?  GTA?  Yes.  Each of these is going to take up ~4GB+ of additional space for SD 1.5-base and ~7GB those based on SDXL.

  Note that LORa's are a lighter-weight way of providing custom-training, and each of these typically runs 144MB (and, while I haven't tried it locally, SDXL LORa's look like they are running just over 200MB).  Textual-inversions are even *more* lightweight, but I think the community has decided that LORa's are the ideal "middle ground" quality/size trade-off between full-blown checkpoints and textual-inversions.
- Images:  Don't forget that you'll ultimately need storage for the images you general with Stable Diffusion.  You might want to let SD just general images continuously from a certain prompt (or even matrix of prompts/settings) to find the ideal result(s).

Answer (score 0):

After posting the above question, I tried refining the search on Google. The resoults page included [How to install and run Stable Diffusion on Apple Silicon M1/M2 Macs](https://stable-diffusion-art.com/install-mac/comment-page-1/). This page include installation instructions for several apps, including Automatic1111 Stable Diffusion Web UI but it's referred just as AUTOMATIC1111.

> This section shows you how to install and run AUTOMATIC1111 on Mac step-by-step.
>
> DiffusionBee is easy to install but the functionality is pretty limited. If you are (or aspired to be) an advanced user, you will want to use an advanced GUI like [AUTOMATIC1111](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui). You will need this GUI if you want to follow my tutorials.

Below the above introduction, the instructions tell you to install Homebrew, and run command line commands, including cloning the Automatic111 Stable Diffusion Web UI repository, and a model.

After the installation, to run the application software, the article instructs to run another command line command and after that open a web browser pointing to a local web server.

While the above doesn't explicitly specify the system requirements as it mentions Apple Silicon M1/M2 I assume that it's fair to assume that any computer models with these CPUs have the required hardware to run the application software.

I will try this later this week.

Answer (score 0):

> At least 10GB disk space.

It's ok to have slightly less than 10GB of disk space. E.g. I installed
[Automatic1111's Stable Diffusion WebUI](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui) using the [Windows 10/11 installer](https://github.com/EmpireMediaScience/A1111-Web-UI-Installer) and kept all the default settings: it's only taking ~8GB of disk space:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The space used is interesting information. It's worth noting that the required free space refers to the space required during the installation process and during the execution time. The installers, including their temporary files, might be deleted after installation to free space, but the application software might still require some free space for their own temporary files. Several years ago there was a rule of thumb saying that computers should always have at least 20% of free storage space.

Comment: This free storage rule of thumb might be different nowadays, but operative systems for consumer devices and application software that runs on them still require that the device has some free space. I'd like to know how much space this app requires during execution.